# How can I create a razor component with binding

Tags: blazor

I created a customized input with label and some spans. (In the following, the spans are not shown, to keep the example simple.)

```
<div>
    <label for="length">length</label>
    <input type="number" id="length" @bind-value="@Length" min="100" max="500">
</div>
<span>@Length</span>

@code {
    private static double length = 300;
    private static int Length
    {
        get => (int)length;
        set => length = value;
    }
}
```

Since i need this customized input several times, I created a razor component LabeledInput.razor:

```
<div>
    <label for="@ID">@LabelText</label>
    <input type="number" id="@ID" @bind-value="@BindValue" min="@Min" max="@Max">
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int BindValue { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string ID { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string LabelText { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public int Max { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public int Min { get; set; }
}
```

But when I use it as

```
[code from above]
<LabeledInput ID="length" LabelText="length2" Min="100" Max="500" BindValue="@Length"></LabeledInput>
```

clicking the spinner buttons of the `LabeledInput` does not update the `<span>@Length</span>` on the GUI. On the other hand, clicking the spinner buttons of the normal `Input` does update the span and also the `LabeledInput`. So, there is a binding but only in one direction.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to create two-way data-binding between the parent component and the child component. To achieve this, you'll have to create a `Value` property in your parent component like this:

```
private int Value { get; set; }
```

The `Value` property requires you to define a prameter property in the child component, like this... Let's call it `Value`

```
[Parameter]
Public int Value { get; set; }
```

In addition you'll have to create an event call back a prameter property like this:

```
[Parameter]
Public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }
```

The `ValueChanged` will contain the event call back that is to be called when
the `ValueChanged` is triggered. Note that the EventCallback is of type int, meaning that you should pass an int value to the method (in our case it is the `Value` property defined in the parent component. Let's see how you call the child component from the parent component:

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"
<Child @bind-Value="@Value" Min="0" Max="100" />
<div>@Value.ToString()</div>

@code
{
    private int Value { get; set; } = 10; // default value
}
```

### Child.razor

```
<div>
    <input type="number" value="@Value" 
           @onchange="@((args) => ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Convert.ToInt32(args.Value)) )" 
           min="@Min" max="@Max">
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public int Max { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public int Min { get; set; }
}
```

Copy, test and then adapt...

Note that instead of providing the @onchange directive with a lambda expression as is done above, you can assign the name of a method, which you'll have to define, and from which you'll have to update the `Value` property

UPDATE:

> Why can't I change the property name Value of the child component?

The rule goes like this: If you name the parameter property `BindValue`, like this:

```
[Parameter]
public int BindValue { get; set; }
```

Then, the EventCallback property should be named: `BindValueChanged`, like this:

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<int> BindValueChanged { get; set; }
```

And it is used in the parent component like this:

```
<Child @bind-BindValue="@Value" Min="0" Max="100" />
```

That is, you apply the @bind directive, plus a hyphen, plus the name of the parameter property defined in the child component. Its value: `"@Value"` is the name of the local property that is bound to the child component, and is updated with a new value passed from the child component, whenever you change the value in the `input type="number"` element. Get it?

Comment: It works. Many thanks! Why can't I change the property name `Value` of the child component? I tried `BindValue` and it compiles but the child component is not visible.

Comment: @Flippowitsch, I've updated my answer...

Comment: Well explained, thanks again. This way, I was even able to bind two values `BindValue` and `BindValue2` to `@Length` and `@Width`.

Comment: My example and your explanation ist for `int`s. I need `double`s now. I changed your default value from 10 to 10.1 and of course the type to double. I also changed everything in the Child component. It compiles but the input does not show the default value but is empty. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding step="0.01" to the input type="number" element.

Comment: That did not work. Does it on your machine?

Comment: Hm, in Firefox the input is not empty. It is "10,1" (with a comma!). But clicking the upper spinner button changes the value to "10.11" for a second, what is then automatically updated to "1011". So, I think, I have an issue with decimal separators. I'll examine tomorrow...

Comment: "That did not work" Did you copy the code from the second answer? I've tested the code with Google Chrome, Brave, Firefox, Edge, and they all work as expected.

Comment: Yes, I copied your code to a new project.

Comment: I created a new Question, because I wanted to provide more information and also the original question is answered. Please find the new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70845705/cultureinfo-issue-with-two-way-binding)